# Jqplot legend size override plot size with using "outsizeGrid"

Tags: javascript, jqplot

i have a question with Jqplot Legend table size, legend table will override my plot size while legend contain a lot of content and i'm using outsizeGrid. I been try using scroll for legend table, but the table have no show any scroll bar and only legend table size is increase.

```
       var legendTable = $($('.jqplot-table-legend')[0]);
        legendTable.css('display', 'block');
        legendTable.css('z-index', 100);
        legendTable.css('height', '100px');
        legendTable.css('overflow-y', 'scroll');
```

[image]